# Do Rank-1 (prenex) polymorphism and Predicative polymorphism mean the same?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, polymorphisms

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism says:

> **Rank-1 (prenex) polymorphism**
>
> In a prenex polymorphic system, **type variables may not be instantiated with polymorphic types**.[4] This is very similar to what is called "ML-style" or
>   "Let-polymorphism" (technically ML's Let-polymorphism has a few other
>   syntactic restrictions). This restriction makes the distinction
>   between polymorphic and non-polymorphic types very important; thus in
>   predicative systems polymorphic types are sometimes referred to as
>   type schemas to distinguish them from ordinary (monomorphic) types,
>   which are sometimes called monotypes. A consequence is that **all
>   types can be written in a form that places all quantifiers at the
>   outermost (prenex) position**. For example, consider the append
>   function described above, which has type
>
> ```
> forall a. [a] × [a] -> [a]
> ```
>
> In order to apply this function to a pair of lists, a type must be
>   substituted for the variable a in the type of the function such that
>   the type of the arguments matches up with the resulting function type.
>   In an impredicative system, the type being substituted may be any type
>   whatsoever, including a type that is itself polymorphic; thus append
>   can be applied to pairs of lists with elements of any type—even to
>   lists of polymorphic functions such as append itself. Polymorphism in
>   the language ML is predicative.[citation needed] This is because
>   predicativity, together with other restrictions, makes the type system
>   simple enough that full type inference is always possible.
>
> As a practical example, OCaml (a descendant or dialect of ML) performs
>   type inference and supports impredicative polymorphism, but in some
>   cases when impredicative polymorphism is used, the system's type
>   inference is incomplete unless some explicit type annotations are
>   provided by the programmer.
>
> ...
>
> **Predicative polymorphism**
>
> In a predicative parametric polymorphic system, a type `τ` containing
>   **a type variable `α` may not be used in such a way that `α` is
>   instantiated to a polymorphic type**. Predicative type theories include
>   Martin-Löf Type Theory and NuPRL.

According to the highlighted sentences,

- Are Rank-1 (prenex) polymorphism and Predicative polymorphism defined  in the same way as "a type variable can't be instantiated to a polymoprhic type"?
- In Rank-1 (prenex) polymorphism, how does "a type variable can't be instantiated to a polymoprhic type" imply "all types can be written in a form that places all quantifiers at the outermost (prenex) position"?

Thanks.